# In a certain year, January had exactly $4$ Mondays and $4$ Fridays. What was the day on $2^{\text{nd}}$ October    the previous year?

Tags: calendar-computations

In a certain year, the month of January had exactly $4$ Mondays and $4$ Fridays. What was the day on [Gandhi Jayanti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandhi_Jayanti) $(2^{\text{nd}}$ October $)$ the previous year?

I am not sure how to approach this one, any ideas?

Comment: I didn't know that there is tag called `calendar-computations`. Thanks @J.M. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As January has 31 days, there are three days that there were 5 of (pigeonhole principle).  The calendar says they must be contiguous, so they must have been Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday.  So Jan 1 was Tuesday.  Then just count back.